# CSS reveal image on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to shift the text up in my navigation menu to reveal a small image where the text was.  With my current code, the image appears under the shifted up text.  Do I need to make a separate CSS element to position the image below the text on hover?  Here is what I have:

```css
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: right;
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
    }
    
    footer * {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    text {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    footer li {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    
    footer li a {
        color: orange;
        font-size: 1.25em text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    }
    
    footer li a:hover {
        position: relative;
        top: -.625em;
        /* shifts navigation element up half the font size on hover */
        background-image: url("../images/fish.png");
        background-position: 50 100;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
    <nav>
        <text>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </text>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: I should clarify, with my current code the background image appears and shifts up with the text on hover.  I want the text to shift up but the image to appear in the text's  original position.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, \there's no way I can test this the way you've added it. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and re-post your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to hover style

> ```
> padding-bottom: 50px;
> width: auto;
> height: 80px;
> ```

That will remove th "blinking" effect. as your hovered text "slips out" the box you are hovering.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do.

You did have a couple of HTML issues.  You can't have an `li` that isn't a direct child of a `ul`.

Secondly, you were missing a semi-colon in your code that was keeping the text-shadow from showing up.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
}

footer * {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

text {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

footer li a {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

footer li a:hover {
  padding-bottom: .625em;
  /* shifts navigation element up half the font size on hover */
  background-position: 50 100;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

footer li a span {
  background: white
}

footer li {
  background-image: url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/bad/fish-1372481.jpg");
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav>
    <text>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Schedule</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     </ul>
     </text>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

What I did was change the negative margin to a bottom padding, so the element still shifts up but does not actually change positions.  I did also mess around with `display` on a few declarations.

In addition, the `vertical-align: bottom;` is important or else all your links will shift up on hover.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting catches.  The background image still shifts up with the text when I hover over the link though.

Comment: Can you add the absolute path to your image so I can play with it?

Comment: I added a sample image and updated my snippit.  The image appears under the nav item that has moved up.

Comment: Wonderful, glad to help!  Please accept the answer so it may help someone else.